# first time using gsap; can't tell why the animation isn't working

Tags: javascript, gsap

```js
const avis1 = document.getElementById('avis1');
const avis2 = document.getElementById('avis2');
const avis3 = document.getElementById('avis3');

const b1_2 = document.getElementById('b1_2');
const b2_3 = document.getElementById('b2_3');
const b2_1 = document.getElementById('b2_1');
const b3_2 = document.getElementById('b3_2');

b1_2.addEventListener('click', () => scrollAvis(avis1, avis2));
b2_3.addEventListener('click', () => scrollAvis(avis2, avis3));
b2_1.addEventListener('click', () => scrollAvis(avis2, avis1));
b3_2.addEventListener('click', () => scrollAvis(avis3, avis2));


function scrollAvis(container,targetElement){
    gsap.to(container, {
        scrollLeft: targetElement.offsetLeft, 
        duration: 0.5,
        ease: "power3.out" });
    console.log("excecuted");
}
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {


    /****** Avis volumaprint: mobile ******/


    .avis{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100vw;
        align-items: center;
      }
      
      .avis__sur-3__left{
        height: 6vw;
      }
      
      .avis__sur-3__right{
        height: 6vw;
      
      }
      
      .avis__sur-3s{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 100vw;
        overflow-x: auto;
      }
      
      .avis__sur-3{
        display: flex;
        width: 90vw;
        padding: 0 5vw;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items:center;
        flex-shrink: 0;
      }
      
      .avis__sur-3__corp{
        display: flex;
        padding: 10vw 0vw;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 4vw;
      }
      
      .avis__title{
        display: flex;
        width: 194px;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 14px;
        z-index: 2;
      }
      
      .avis__title__line{
        width: 195px;
        bottom: -45px;
        stroke-width: 6px;
        position:relative ;
      }
      
      .avis__title__text{
        color: #000;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 700;
        line-height: 36px; /* 180% */
      }
      
      .avis__sur-3__auteur{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 9px;
      }
      
      .avis__sur-3__auteur__text{
        color: #000;
      
        /* Body (medium) */
        font-family: Lato;
        font-size: 5vw;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 500;
        line-height: 5vw; /* 133.333% */
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      .avis__sur-3__auteur__img{
        width: 140px;
        height: 24px;
      }
      
      .avis__sur-3__text{
        color: #000;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        font-size: 4vw;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 500;
        line-height: 28px; /* 175% */
      }

      
    }

    
  @media screen and (min-width: 960px) {

        /****** Avis volumaprint: desktop ******/


  .avis__sur-3__left{
    height: 3vw;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .avis__sur-3__right{  
    height: 3vw;
    position: relative;
  
  }
  
  .avis{
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2vw 0;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 4px;
  }

  .avis__sur-3s{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .avis__sur-3{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
  
  .avis__sur-3__corp{
    display: flex;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 4vw 0vw;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2vw;
  }
  
  .avis__title{
    display: flex;
    width: 194px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 14px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .avis__title__line{
    width: 195px;
    bottom: -45px;
    stroke-width: 6px;
    position:relative ;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .avis__title__text{
    color: #000;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 36px; /* 180% */
  }
  
  .avis__sur-3__auteur{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1vw;
  }
  
  .avis__sur-3__auteur__text{
    color: #000;
  
    /* Body (medium) */
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 5vw; /* 133.333% */
    /* text-align: center; */
  }
  
  .avis__sur-3__auteur__img{
    width: 140px;
    height: 24px;
  }
  
  .avis__sur-3__text{
    align-self: stretch;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 28px; /* 175% */
  }

}
```

```html
 <div class="avis">
            <section class="avis__title">
                <svg class="avis__title__line" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="195" height="6" viewBox="0 0 195 6" fill="none">
                    <path d="M0 3H195" stroke="#FFF59D" stroke-width="6"/>
                </svg>
                <h2 class="avis__title__text">
                    Avis de nos clients
                </h2>
            </section>
            <div class="avis__sur-3s">
                <div id="avis1" class="avis__sur-3">
                    <img class="avis__sur-3__left" alt="" src="img/icons/arrow_circle_left-gray.svg">
                    <div class="avis__sur-3__corp">
                        <div class="avis__sur-3__auteur">
                            <p class="avis__sur-3__auteur__text">
                                GOA - Génération OPTIQ AUDIO
                            </p>
                            <img class="avis__sur-3__auteur__img" src="img/rating.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <p class="avis__sur-3__text">
                            “ Je loue un photocopieur depuis maintenant plusieurs années à Volumaprint, tout s'est toujours bien passé, réactivité et service au top ! Je recommande vivement!! “
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <img id="b1_2" class="avis__sur-3__right" alt="" src="img/icons/arrow_circle_right.svg">

                </div>
                <div id="avis2" class="avis__sur-3">
                    <img id="b2_3" class="avis__sur-3__left" alt="" src="img/icons/arrow_circle_left.svg">
                    <div class="avis__sur-3__corp">
                        <div class="avis__sur-3__auteur">
                            <p class="avis__sur-3__auteur__text">
                                GOA - Génération OPTIQ AUDIO
                            </p>
                            <img class="avis__sur-3__auteur__img" src="img/rating.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <p class="avis__sur-3__text">
                            “ Je loue un photocopieur depuis maintenant plusieurs années à Volumaprint, tout s'est toujours bien passé, réactivité et service au top ! Je recommande vivement!! “
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <img id="b2_1" class="avis__sur-3__right" alt="" src="img/icons/arrow_circle_right.svg">

                </div>
                <div id="avis3" class="avis__sur-3">
                    <img id="b3_2" class="avis__sur-3__left" alt="" src="img/icons/arrow_circle_left.svg">
                    <div class="avis__sur-3__corp">
                        <div class="avis__sur-3__auteur">
                            <p class="avis__sur-3__auteur__text">
                                GOA - Génération OPTIQ AUDIO
                            </p>
                            <img class="avis__sur-3__auteur__img" src="img/rating.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <p class="avis__sur-3__text">
                            “ Je loue un photocopieur depuis maintenant plusieurs années à Volumaprint, tout s'est toujours bien passé, réactivité et service au top ! Je recommande vivement!! “
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <img class="avis__sur-3__right" alt="" src="img/icons/arrow_circle_right-gray.svg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the function does get excecuted but the animation doesn't occur

here is the code: const declarations + function

```
const avis1 = document.getElementById('avis1');
const avis2 = document.getElementById('avis2');
const avis3 = document.getElementById('avis3');

const b1_2 = document.getElementById('b1_2');
const b2_3 = document.getElementById('b2_3');
const b2_1 = document.getElementById('b2_1');
const b3_2 = document.getElementById('b3_2');

b1_2.addEventListener('click', () => scrollAvis(avis1, avis2));
b2_3.addEventListener('click', () => scrollAvis(avis2, avis3));
b2_1.addEventListener('click', () => scrollAvis(avis2, avis1));
b3_2.addEventListener('click', () => scrollAvis(avis3, avis2));


function scrollAvis(container,targetElement){
    gsap.to(container, {
        scrollLeft: targetElement.offsetLeft, 
        duration: 0.5,
        ease: "power3.out" });
    console.log("excecuted");
}
```

i verified the HTML and CSS, verified that the function gets excecuted and it does but the animation doesn't occur.

as this is the first time i'm using gsap, i'm also relatively new to  javascript.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

Comment: You can use `<>` to add a working snippet

Comment: It would be almost feature complete if you also included your HTML. The issue is that if the mistake is in your HTML, then we would have no way of knowing that and we could take a stab at helping you but would _never_ find a solution that would work.

Comment: @somethinghere thank you for bringing it up, i have now included snippets

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution, this is fully working now.

```
console.clear(); // Start with a clean console on refesh 
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollToPlugin);

const avis1 = document.getElementById("avis1");
const avis2 = document.getElementById("avis2");
const avis3 = document.getElementById("avis3");

const b1_2 = document.getElementById("b1_2");
const b2_3 = document.getElementById("b2_3");
const b2_1 = document.getElementById("b2_1");
const b3_2 = document.getElementById("b3_2");

b1_2.addEventListener("click", () => scrollAvis(avis1, avis2));
b2_3.addEventListener("click", () => scrollAvis(avis2, avis3));
b2_1.addEventListener("click", () => scrollAvis(avis2, avis1));
b3_2.addEventListener("click", () => scrollAvis(avis3, avis2));

function scrollAvis(container, targetElement) {
  console.warn(container);
  console.log(targetElement);
  
  gsap.to(".avis__sur-3s", {
    scrollTo: {
      x: targetElement
    },
    duration: 0.5,
    ease: "power3.out"
  });
  
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).